# Error while importing Farseer Physics Engine

Tags: box2d, game-physics, monogame, farseer

When I import Farseer Physics Monogame to my project and add the dependency then I am getting this error as mentioned below. I would appreciate any help. Also is there any other Physics engine which is a better alternative and have well documentation and can be used with Monogame.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly
>   'FarseerPhysics MonoGame, Version=, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='.
>   Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile? File name:
>   'FarseerPhysics MonoGame.dll'    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String
>   fullName, ReaderParameters parameters)    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve(String
>   fullName)    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Cecil.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.GetAssembly(String
>   fileName)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Extract(ICollection`1
>   jars, ICollection`1 resolvedResourceDirectories, ICollection`1
>   resolvedAssetDirectories, ICollection`1 resolvedEnvironments)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveLibraryProjectImports.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() Mono2DLearning

Comment: Farseer is your best bet for physics on XNA/Monogame.

Get an older build if you can't get this working.

Comment: A while ago I compiled Farseer as a PCL against the MonoGame PCL. It worked like a charm at the time and should work for your situation with minimal effort. The code is [on github](https://github.com/craftworkgames/FarseerPhysics.Portable)